# Regex - Globally replace a slash in between given XML tags only

Tags: regex, xml, ant

I'm trying to replace backslashes by forwardslashes, globally, over several lines, in an xml file but only in a given tag.

Example where I want to work on the content of `Path`:

```
<name>file1</name><path>c:\folder\folder</path><test>just\the\lolz</test>
<name>file2</name><path>c:\folder\folder\folder</path><test>some more\lolz</test>
```

Should become:

```
<name>file1</name><path>c:/folder/folder</path><test>just\the\lolz</test>
<name>file2</name><path>c:/folder/folder/folder</path><test>some more\lolz</test>
```

I've been trying with look arounds and recursion but I'm getting nowhere...
Last useless try was:

```
(?<=path>)(\w*?(\x2F))+(?=.*<\/path>)
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would be a lot easier to load the XML and replace the node value. What language are you using?

Comment: I'm in an ant script, I'm turning a txt file into xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for this:

```
(?<=path>[^<]*)\\
```

And replace with this:

```
/
```

It's worth cautioning you that this will not work with any and every XML file.  Truly parsing XML files and properly handling any and all possible legal XML is not possible (or at least recommended) with regex, but as long as the data is consistent, that should suffice.

Comment: Same thing, regex101 tells me you can't use quantifiers in lookarounds (*). I've tried that already :(

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need: `(?<=<path>.*)\/(?=.*<\/path>)`

**Note:** Does not work in JavaScript, because JavaScript does not support lookbehinds.

Let me explain:

`(?<=<path>.*)` this is a lookbehind for  and any characters until it finds  preceding the character you insert after it in our case `\/` (an escaped `/` )

`(?=.*<\/path>)` this is a lookahead, works the same as the lookbehind, but searches everything to the right of the string preceding it, in our case the `/`. The lookahead does work in JavaScript.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Sorry, regex101 tells me you can't use quantifiers in lookarounds (*). I've tried that already :(

Comment: Alright, you could use a str_replace function to replace this regex-match: (?<=path>).*(?=<\/path) by the same string formatted with str_replace to replace the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple selecting phrases between `<path>...</path>`

```
(?<=path>).*(?=<\/path)
```

Example in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eH4gB8/1)

Comment: That I know how to do ;) How to get the slashes though? Difficult for me.